# How to un-batch in PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch, nlp, bert-language-model, huggingface

I have a very simple text encoding script that implements BERT. I want to pass a set of texts through BERT and store it's output for further investigation.

I create a dataloader with tokenized text, pass it through BERT, and store the last hidden state as my output. After the model processes each batch, i iterate through the batch and copy each output into the outputs list.

The problem is that if the number of texts is not divisible by BATCH, the dataloader is padding the last batch to make it have BATCH samples, but in forming my outputs list, I don't know which samples are real and which are pads.

I'm sure this is not the best way to go about this task and would appreciate any advice. Currently using BATCH=1 (does this even matter if I'm not training?)

Second, unrelated question: is last_hidden_state the best thing to use as an encoding? If my max_length = 512 but i have a short text sequence will the padded tokens dilute the encoding?

I appreciate your advice, code below.

```
X = tokenizer(corpus, padding="max_length", truncation=True, max_length=512, return_tensors="pt")
X = TensorDataset(torch.tensor(X['input_ids']), torch.tensor(X['attention_mask']))
dl = DataLoader(X, pin_memory=True, batch_size = 32)


class Encoder(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, ):
    super(Encoder, self).__init__()
    self.bert = pretrained_model
    #self.transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()])

def forward(self, sent_id, mask):
    x = self.bert(sent_id, attention_mask=mask).last_hidden_state[:, 0, :]
    
    return x


model = Encoder().to(device)
outputs = []
iterator = iter(dl)

for i in range(len(dl)):
    batch = next(iterator)
    a = model(batch[0].to(device), batch[1].to(device)).detach().cpu().numpy()
    for j in range(a.shape[0]):
        outputs.append(a[j,:])
```

Of note, I am using Huggingface AutoModel and AutoTokenizer.

Answer (score 0):

1. 

If I understand correctly, you want to save the `last_hidden_state` of the model for each of your input samples for further postprocessing. My approach would be as follows:

```py
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("gpt2", output_hidden_states=True).to("cuda")
outputs = []
for i, batch in enumerate(dataloader):
    batch = {k: v.to("cuda") for k, v in batch.items()}
    output = model(batch["input_ids"], attention_mask=batch["attention_mask"])
    # get the last layer's hidden states
    last_hidden_state = output.hidden_states[-1]  # (batch_size, seq_len, hidden_dim)
    last_hidden_state_masked = last_hidden_state * batch["attention_mask"].unsqueeze(2)
    outputs.append(last_hidden_state_masked.detach().cpu().numpy())
```

*Note that the way you retrieve the last_hidden_state depends on what model you instantiate and how you instantiate it.*
You can do `last_hidden_states * batch["attention_mask"].unsqueeze(2)` as the attention mask contains 1's for normal tokens and 0's for padding tokens. You have to call `unsqueeze(2)` as `batch["attention_mask"].shape = (batch_size, seq_len)`.
This will set all the values in the last_hidden_states to 0 for the padding tokens.

Each np array in `outputs` is of shape `(batch_size, seq_len, hidden_dim)`.
Afterwards, you can ignore the arrays in each `last_hidden_state` np array that contain only 0's:

```py
for output in outputs:
    is_nonzero = np.all(output != 0, axis=2)
    filtered_output = output[is_nonzero]
    ...
```

2. 

> is last_hidden_state the best thing to use as an encoding? If my
> max_length = 512 but i have a short text sequence will the padded
> tokens dilute the encoding?

Yes, it's a good idea to use the `last_hidden_states` as embeddings for your input text for further applications. You can typically ignore the padding tokens to get meaningful embeddings by applying the code above.